# validate regex submatches

Tags: java, regex, match

I have the following word:

- `E012PH345AN678T`

and the following regular expression:

- `^E(.*)?(PH(.*)?AN|AN(.*)?PH)(.*)?T$`

This will trigger the following matches:

- 1: 012
- 2: PH345AN
- 3: 345
- 4:
- 5: 678

Is there any way to make sure that sub-matches (1,3,4,5) contain at least 3 digits inside the same regular expression (a-la `(\1\3\4\5)\d{3,}`)? The regex will be ran in a Java environment on which I cannot control too much.

**Update** - as an additional example, this `EXY2PHZ45ANUWT` should also match ... I just need to find the `2,4,5` in the matches, on the global level. The digits are just a simplified example of what I need ... can be letters or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/jO6zT2/10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your regex as

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d.*)E(.*)?(PH(.*)?AN|AN(.*)?PH)(.*)?T$
```

This will match the input if and only if it has at least three digits, no matter in which sub-group they are captured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=(\D*\d){3})E(.*?)(PH(.*?)AN|AN(.*?)PH)(.*?)T$
```

`(?=\d{3})` is a lookahead that make sure at least 3 digits are there in your input.

In Java:

```
^(?=(\\D*\\d){3})E(.*?)(PH(.*?)AN|AN(.*?)PH)(.*?)T$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN3uQ1/2)

Comment: \d{3} will match 3 digits exactly. To have 3 or more, use \d{3,} instead.

Comment: @mazaneicha: No, same regex will also match `E01234PH345AN678T`. `(?=\d{3})` is to make sure **at least 3 digits are there**, there can be more than 3 also.

Comment: I want at least 3 digits on the global level. not each match to have 3 digits. I have updated the post. EXY2PHZ45ANUWT should be also a match ...